# What is the Shine–Dalgarno sequence?

Tags: translation, mrna, ribosome, prokaryotes

I am trying to understand the Shine–Dalgarno sequence. I currently know it is related to ribosomal binding sites, it is only found in prokaryote cells and it is in front of the initial codon. Also, how do you recognize a Shine-Dalgarno sequence?

Answer (score 4):

According to [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shine-Dalgarno_sequence):

> "The Shine-Dalgarno (SD) sequence is a ribosomal binding site in
>   bacterial and archaeal messenger RNA, generally located around 8 bases
>   upstream of the start codon AUG.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shine-Dalgarno_sequence) The RNA sequence helps recruit the
>   ribosome to the messenger RNA (mRNA) to initiate protein synthesis by
>   aligning the ribosome with the start codon.
>
> The Shine-Dalgarno sequence exists both in bacteria and archaea. It is
>   also present in some chloroplast and mitochondrial transcripts. The
>   six-base consensus sequence is AGGAGG; in Escherichia coli, for
>   example, the sequence is AGGAGGU..."

I hope this gives the insight that you needed.